# Phrase comportant « être commencé(e) »

Tags: constructions, auxiliaires, passif

Le verbe commencer se conjugue avec l'auxiliaire *avoir*.
Cependant, j'ai vu la proposition :

> Et, bien sûr, le devoir à rendre demain n'est pas commencé…

Que signifie « être commencé(e) » ? S'agit-il de la voix passive ?

Quand peut-on utiliser cette construction, « être commencé » ?

Avec quels verbes peut-on employer une telle construction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il ne s'agit pas d'une voix passive. C'est une construction attributive dans laquelle le verbe *être* n'est pas un auxiliaire. Le participe passé *commencé* est simplement utilisé comme un adjectif. La structure de « le devoir n'est pas commencé » est la même que celle de « le devoir n'est pas difficile ».

Cette construction est possible avec tous les participes passés qui peuvent être utilisés comme des adjectifs. En français¹ seul le contexte permet de savoir s'il s'agit d'une construction attributive ou passive. Par exemple, la phrase suivante :

> La route est construite

est généralement comprise comme décrivant état (construction attributive) avec un aspect accompli, plutôt qu'une action en cours à la voix passive comme dans :

> La route est construite en hâte par les exploitants.

Dans le premier cas le verbe est *être*, dans le deuxième c'est *construire*. Il y a une grosse différence de sens, car dans le premier cas la route est finie alors que dans le deuxième elle ne l'est pas.

Dans l'exemple qui nous intéresse :

> Et, bien sûr, le devoir à rendre demain n'est pas commencé…

le contexte nous fait comprendre qu'il s'agit d'une remarque sur l'état, pas sur une action en cours.

—
<sup>1. En allemand, par exemple, il y aurait une différence.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

C'est une voix passive tout ce qu'il y a de plus normale. Comme tout les passifs, elle s'emploie avec n'importe quel verbe transitif présentant un objet, ce qui est le cas de la phrase *J'ai commencé mon devoir*.

Comment: Désolé de mon retour tardif. Ta réponse contredit celle de Stéphane.