# Sens de 'La porte est ouverte.'

Tags: grammaire, traduction, usage, passif, attributs

Sans connaître le contexte la phrase

> La porte est ouverte.

signifie, par défaut,  l'état

> The door is open.

ou l'action

> The door is being opened.

?

Comment: In line with the accepted answer, I would go further and say that no context would make that fragment, on its own, mean the present progressive "is being opened". If anything it could be (a) something that regularly happens or (b) the historic present, but still neither is the most natural interpretation.

Comment: Cf. [“être commencé”](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29233/phrase-comportant-%c3%aatre-commenc%c3%a9e)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sans connaître le contexte, c'est l'état dont il est question. Pour l'action, on dirait plutôt "on ouvre la porte" ou "la porte s'ouvre".

Answer (score 4):

Dans ce cas là il faut absolument préciser le contexte.
Sans précision je pense qu'il s'agit d'un état:

> The door is open

Mais cela pourrait s'inscrire dans une action, par exemple:

> la porte est ouverte par Pierre